# CsvHelper throws an error "cannot access a disposed object" while parsing a csv file from ftp

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to parse a `.csv` file using CsvHelper. If I try to parse the data into dynamic object from ftp path, I get an error

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

Here is my code

```
private WebRequest CreateRequest(string method)
{
    WebRequest req = null;

    try
    {
        req = WebRequest.Create(_host + folderpath);
        req.Method = method;
        req.Credentials = _credentials;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return req;     
}

public void ReadCSVData(string filename)
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    folderpath = folderpath + "/" + filename;

    var request = CreateRequest(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile);

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var records = csvReader.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The stacktrace for the error:

```
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at CsvHelper.CsvParser.Read()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.Read()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.<GetRecords>d__87`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at FleetcheckDownLoad.FTP.ReadCSVData(String filename) in C:\FleetcheckDownLoad\FleetcheckDownLoad\FTP.cs:line 188
   at FleetcheckDownLoad.DownLoad.dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) in C:\FleetcheckDownLoad\FleetcheckDownLoad\DownLoad.cs:line 58
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellDoubleClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
```

Comment: So every time you run this code, you get the exact same error? What's the stack trace look like (please edit your question to include it)?

Comment: Yes , I am getting this error all the time when I read a csv file  from ftp server using csvHelper

Comment: 1) What happens if you just do `var text = reader.ReadToEnd()`?  Can the FTP response stream be read successfully into a string?  2) Is the ObjectDisposedException thrown after the entire CSV is read into the `records` list, or before?  Are any records read successfully?

Comment: Also, I don't suppose you have a CSV file available on an FTP server we could use to reproduce the problem ourselves, do you?

Comment: Just a guess, but you map the CsvReader directly onto the responseStream. A NetworkStream cannot Seek.  You could try copying it to a MemoryStream first, and then use that to read it as CSV.

Comment: I'm pretty sure CsvReader is forward-only and doesn't seek.  However, I did find this bug specific to NetworkStream: [Reading from FTP stream throws ObjectDisposedException regarding "NetworkStream"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/reading-from-ftp-stream-throws-objectdisposedexcep/633720)...

Comment: ... The bug is that, if the application tries to read 0 bytes from the stream for some reason, the underlying connection is closed.  It's possible, though unlikely, that CsvReader is trying to do that somewhere e.g. when populating its buffer or checking to see whether there are additional lines to read.  That's why having a [mcve] including a CSV file available on an FTP server would help us to sort this out.  That being said, the idea of @HenkHolterman to copy to a `MemoryStream` and deserialize from that may very well fix the problem whatever the cause may be.